# TDD with reactjs, reactify, babelify, browserify, gulp

Tags: reactjs, tdd, gulp, browserify

I am looking for running test on a project which use :

- browserify *with these transform* :

  - babelify
  - reactify

I did try the combo JSDOM + Mocha but testing a component which has not been builded yet will fail on require call from a component to another :

```
> mocha --compilers js:babel/register --recursive

module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'system/services/AuthService'
```

I think I need to run mocha test during the gulp build watchify and build tasks. I am not sure if handling the test during the build process is a good option.

Normaly, after a successful build I have a file in `client/build/js/bundle.js` in ES5.

I want to be able to test my component using the ES6 file which require a browserify for being readble by my testing lib.

Does anyone could provide me a good option, with some npm modules or anything that could help me achieve TDD in my environment ?

Comment: Well worth a shot in my opinion: http://reactjsnews.com/testing-the-easy-way/ or if you'd rather go the usual way http://reactjsnews.com/testing-in-react/

Comment: Thanks but both examples shows how to use test tools, but not how import by require from app components are managed. This will fail when I'll require a file that does require some other file accessible only through browserify

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Mochify is a good fit for your use case. Here's a React example: https://github.com/mantoni/mochify.js/wiki/Testing-a-ReactJS-Component-with-Mochify

Comment: Dude, it's exactly the same probleme, this example shows a React component called HelloReact, which doesn't import any external files that need to be required from browserify, if my question isn't clear enough, please tell me so

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. I read that you want TDD with browserify , mocha and react. I've sent a link to an example doing exactly that. If you want to put some additional require statements in there, I don't see why that shouldn't work. It's just a small example to keep things short. If you want babel in the mix, just add the babelify transform to your package.json.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but has I told you, this work as long as the tested file is not dependant on other js files from React project. Since react is component based logic, you mostly won't be able to test your component that way, since you have to build before.